# how to get max and sum of 2nd column of array in ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, sum, max

for an array like

> s = [[1,2],[4,6],[2,7]]

How i can select max and sum of 2nd column in each row in one statement

max= 7
sum= 15

I know, that

```
sum = 0
max = 0
s.each{ |a,b| sum+=b;if max<b then max = b end }
```

would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`s.map{|e| e[1]}.max` gives you max

`s.map{|e| e[1]}.reduce(:+)` gives you sum.

Comment: s.flatten.max returns max of all array. for example in [[3,2]] i want to return 2 not 3

Answer (score 2):

```
second_elements = s.map { |el| el[1] }
sum = second_elements.inject{|sum,x| sum + x }
max = second_elements.max
```

To be more clear:
`inject{|sum,x| sum + x }` returns nil if array is empty, so if you want to get 0 for empty array then use `inject(0, :+)`

Comment: its ok!! what i need is: max = s.map { |el| el[1] }.max

Comment: @railscard: any idea why I get: `NoMethodError: undefined method 'sum' for [2, 6, 7]:Array` ?

Comment: @sawa but it is ok for getting max.

Comment: @MarcinDoliwa `sum` is a method from the activesupport gem.

Comment: This is the better answer as it avoids calculating the array of second elements twice.

Answer (score 2):

[The transpose method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-transpose) is nice for accessing "columns":

```
s = [[1,2],[4,6],[2,7]]
col = s.transpose[1]
p col.max #=> 7
p col.inject(:+) #=> 15
```

Answer (score 2):

```
s.max {|a| a[1]}[1]          # Max of elements at index 1
s.max {|a| a.last }.last     # Max of last elements
# => 7
```

To find the sum, if you use Ruby 2.4 or greater / if you are on Rails

```
s.sum {|a| a[1]}             # Sum of elements at index 1
s.sum(&:last)                # Sum of last elements
# => 15
```

else

```
s.inject(0) {|sum, a| sum+= a[1] }
# => 15
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s = [[1,2],[4,6],[2,7]]
second_max = s.max_by(&:last).last 
# => 7
sum = s.reduce(0){|sum,a| sum + a.last}
# => 15
```